# Can bus stop icons in Baidu map(created through the API) be made clickable?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am wondering if bus stop icons embedded in map (maps created using Google API or Baidu API) can be made clickable? I am aware that someone mentioned in another post of the legal issues regarding real-time data between the maps service provider and the public transport agencies. However, what if I just want to make the bus stop icons clickable mainly to show bus stop information such as bus service numbers and name(in the case of Baidu Map), is there any ways to do that? Those information can be obtained from the API so I do not think there is any legal issues compromised.

I am aware that I can simply just search for the bus stops and create markers to mark the points, and open the info window by clicking on the markers. However I feel that it will be better to enable the bus stop icons (already show on the map) clickable instead of displaying more markers.

Any information and help regarding this issue will be greatly appreciated. :)
(I'm using Baidu Map v1.3 btw)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769966/google-map-api-open-url-by-clicking-at-marker

Comment: That is regarding using markers which I already have a solution. I am asking about that small little bus icons indicating bus stops on the map

Comment: Can those bus stop icons be removed or hidden instead? I think google map is able to do that, but what about Baidu?