# Ad a url to a google map marker?

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, url, google-maps-markers

I would like to plot a list of markers on a google map. I generate some Javascript code using Python. I read this : [google map api: open url by clicking at marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769966/google-map-api-open-url-by-clicking-at-marker) and try to adapt my code but it still doesn t work : all I am able to plot is the first maker and the url doesn' t even look like it is working.

Here is what I produced since then - I tried to keep it as simple as possible.

```
from __future__ import print_function

class Mappy(object):
    def __init__(self,listCord=[]):
         self.listCord = listCord
    def __str__(self):
         initLat = sum(( x[0] for x in self.listCord)) / len(self.listCord)
         initLon = sum(( x[1] for x in self.listCord)) / len(self.listCord)

         markersCode = "\n".join(
             [ """new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: new google.maps.LatLng(%s,%s),
                  map: map,
                  title : '%s',
                  url : '%s'
                  });

                  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click',   function() {
            window.location.href = this.url;
            });

            """%(x[0], x[1],x[2],x[2]) 
            for x in self.listCord])

         print (markersCode)
         return """
            <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
            <div id="map-canvas" style="height: 100%; width: 100%"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var map;
                function show_map() {{
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {{
                        zoom: 8,
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng({centerLat}, {centerLon})
                }});
                {markersCode}
            }}
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', show_map);
        </script>
    """.format(centerLat=initLat, centerLon=initLon,
               markersCode=markersCode)
```

Now that the class tht will generate the list of marker is set up, this is my main:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    listCord = [[51.5248,-0.133427,'Old Trafford','http://www.manutd.com'],
                [51.5145,-0.157687,'Stamford Bridge','http://www.chelseafc.com'],
                [51.5264,-0.13892,'Anfield','http://www.liverpoolfc.com']]

    mapper = Mappy(listCord)

    with open('stadium.html','w') as out :
        print(mapper,file=out)
```

This will return a HTML file where I am suposed to see my place of interest with their link. But it doesnt work. I have to say that if I don t put the :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click',   function() {
        window.location.href = this.url;
        });
```

I can then see all the place on my map with their title.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

looks like you just have to change a single line of your code to make it work!

try using `window.open(marker.url);`instead of `window.location.href = marker.url;`

Check out the example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNJKzX)